# Erro ao renderizar componente

Tags: vue.js

A página no navegador só fica em branco e no console aparece o seguinte erro:

```
Failed to resolve directive: ref
```

Depois de ficar comentando e descomentando várias partes do meu código, descobri que a página só funciona certinho quando eu comento essa linha:

```
<h3>{{ status }}</h3>
```

Estou usando Vue.js 2. Esse status é computed:

```
computed: {
    status: function(){
        var count = 0;
        var lista = this.$refs.listaComponent;
        for(var i in lista.contas){
            if (!lista.contas[i].pago) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return !count ? "Nenhuma conta a pagar." : "Existem " + count + " contas a pagar.";
    }
},
```

Meu HTML tem essa linha:

```
<lista-component v-ref:lista-component></lista-component>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Vue.js 2.0 a diretiva `v-ref` virou apenas `ref`, de acordo com a [documentação](https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#v-el-and-v-ref-replaced).

Esta é a forma correta:

```
<lista-component ref="lista-component"></lista-component>
```

Answer (score 1):

Guilherme, queria escrever como comentário minha dúvida mas não tenho pontos pra isso.. rs

Enfim, como você declarou esse componente? Você se lembrou de instanciar seu obj Vue? Pode mandar um link do JSfiddle?

Na declaração do componente, você precisa instanciar seu obj Vue, mais ou menos como isso:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  }
})
```

Comment: Sei como é haha, no SO Americano eu também não posso comentar. Está certinho, Até porque se eu comentar aquela linha que está no template do componente ele funciona certinho. Então cheguei a conclusão que o problema está no computed. E pesquisando aqui parece que o problema tem a ver com o v-ref. Talvez seja porque eu estou adaptando para rotas?

Comment: Reparei agora que o erro mudou para: `Failed to resolve directive: ref`